# Add-Migration fails because EntityFrameworkCore.Tools is not installed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I want to create a console application with EF Core by following this tutorial: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/full-dotnet/new-db.html.

My problem is, I cannot execute the statement

```
Add-Migration
```

as described in the tutorials. It shows me:

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
Cannot execute this command because 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' is not installed in project 'src\AppEf'. Add 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' to the 'tools' section in project.json. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for more details.
```

All added assemblies:

[image]

What is wrong?

**Update**

The statement `dotnet restore` works and `dotnet-ef --help` does not work at all.
[image]

And you can see, the statement is execute in project folder.

Comment: According to your screenshot you have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` listed under `dependencies` in `project.json`.  What the message is telling you is it needs to be under `tools`. (It probably should be in both places - not sure I'm still in the process of migrating to RTM.)

Comment: So what do I have to do?

Comment: You need to edit the `project.json`.  Add a "tools" object/section and add "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" to it.

Comment: I did it and try to compile and it shows me `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\.tools\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.`

Comment: That sounds like a syntax error in your project.json (if so most likely a missing or extraneous comma)? What does Solution Explorer look like now?

Comment: Or you may need to add "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" to "tools" as well.

Comment: FYI, you're looking at the wrong tutorial. That one is for **full .NET**. The .NET Core tutorial is here: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/netcore/new-db-sqlite.html

Answer (score 7):

As a few people mentioned in the comments, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` needs to be added to the `tools` section of project.json.

I've tested this project.json with the latest (July 2016) versions of EF Core and the tooling packages, and it works:

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

To use it, execute these commands from **inside** the project folder:

```
λ dotnet restore
log  : Restore completed in 2810ms.

λ dotnet ef --help
Compiling EfCoreTester2 for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0                                                                            
Compilation succeeded.                                                                                                          
    0 Warning(s)                                                                                                                
    0 Error(s)                                                                                                                  
Time elapsed 00:00:01.7208394                                                                                                   

Entity Framework .NET Core CLI Commands 1.0.0-preview2-21431
Usage: dotnet ef [options] [command]
Options:
  -h|--help                      Show help information
  -v|--verbose                   Enable verbose output
  --version                      Show version information
(... etc)
```

At first, I was getting `No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"` until I realized that you have to execute the commands from inside the project folder (`src\projectName` in my case). If you try to do it from the solution root directory, it won't work.

Comment: As this answer hasn't been marked as correct (at the time of writing) - It is the correct answer if you are doing the EF Reverse Engineering Tutorial and didn't read the instructions properly (I skimmed that section thinking it was just showing you where the references were) - https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#create-a-new-project

Comment: So, do we select the project from from the Default project dropdown, or type the project folder into the command line? thanks

Comment: @Kleky I'm running these commands from PowerShell, not the integrated console window.

Comment: Yes, the trick is to "cd" into the project folder, then run the dotnet ef something...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with such package configuration

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "type": "platform"
  },
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
  ...
}

"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final"
},
```

and this command works

```
Scaffold-DbContext
    "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=<DB name>;Integrated Security=True;"
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"
    -OutputDir Entities
    -Context "ApplicationDbContext"
    -DataAnnotations
    -Force
    -Project <Project name>.Data
    -StartupProject <Project name>.Api
```

Here I scaffold a context into a separate class library project with name `Data` where the web app is `Api`