# Entity Framework Core Add-Migration cannot execute

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to to set up a new database/migrations with Entity Framework Core (version 1.1.0) on a .NET application.

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.
```

I have already installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (along with Tools (version 1.1.0-preview4-final), and the Relational/Relational.Design and Sqlite packages). I can see this in the Nuget package manager.

Now this does seem similar to this Q&A - [Entity Framework Core 1.0.1 add-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751199/entity-framework-core-1-0-1-add-migration) - but there's a few differences, mainly there is no `project.json` anywhere, and the error message is slightly different.

There is a `packages.config` file which has this in it.

```
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" version="1.1.0-preview4-final" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
```

Comment: This is somehow related but not similar as you have `packages.config` and they have `packages.json` file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306791/add-migration-fails-because-entityframeworkcore-tools-is-not-installed

Comment: When you say "I have already installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (along with Tools (version 1.1.0-preview4-final), and the Relational/Relational.Design and Sqlite packages)", did you install 1.1.0 using [Nuget Beta Channel](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/install-nuget#nuget-beta-channel)? If not, can you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` package in not only the class library that implemented the `DbContext` class, but also in the project (in this case the GUI/WinForms project) that referenced said class library. This was despite having selected the class library in the Package Manager Console as user Derek suggested.

Once I did this I was able to run the `Add-Migration` command and related commands.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the project selected in the package manager console that has EntityFramework Installed.

Comment: I have done that but still get the above error messages. It's a multi project solution and I'm selecting the project which implements the DbContext and has all the EntityFrameworkCore references installed from Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the LTS (1.0.x) rumtime installed? Find it on [the downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) page.

(It may not help, but it's one possible issue.)

Comment: Assuming you mean .NET Core, I'll give this a go. Also updated from Visual Studio 2015 'Update 2' to 'Update 3' last night, just in case this has something to do with it.